# Как потоки кэшируют переменные или особенности работы volatile

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency, volatile

Есть класс сущность с двумя полям (bool/int) и два потока, которые принимаю один и тот же объект этого класса.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
     Entity entity;
     public MyThread(Entity entity) { this.entity = entity; } 
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Entity {
    private Boolean flag = false;
    private int count = 10;
}
```

Один поток опрашивает флаг и пока он false - выводит значение целочисленной переменной count.
Второй поток через секунду меняет значение флага на true, а также изменяет значение переменной count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Entity entity = new Entity();

    new MyThread(entity) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!entity.getFlag()) {
                System.out.println(entity.getCount());
            }
            System.out.println(entity.getCount());
        }
    }.start();

    new MyThread(entity) {
        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            entity.setCount(9999);
            entity.setFlag(true);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Ожидаемое поведение - первый поток зациклится, поскольку он закеширует boolean переменную и не увидит ее изменения вторым поток. Для исправления этой ситуации нужно добавить volatile флагу.
Фактическое поведение - на одной машине действительно так работает, на другой зацикливания не происходит. Первый поток останавливается без всякого volatile.

Ситуация номер 2.

Я добавляю volatile только флагу, но не count переменной. Я ожидаю, что первый поток прекратит свое выполнение, но выведет исключительно значение 10 (напомню, что второй поток  count переменную меняет), т.к. он закешировал count и не увидит изменения от второго потока.
Фактическое поведение - первый всегда в конце выводит обновленное значение count, как будто он ничего не кешировал и увидел изменения от второго потока. Без всякого volatile.

Почему?

P.S. Это абстрактная задача на понимание работы volatile. Предлагать альтернативные решения не нужно)

Comment: `Ожидаемое поведение - первый поток зациклится, поскольку он закеширует boolean` - не, ожидаемое поведение "оно может закешироваться". Собственно это Вы и наблюдаете. Вам повезло. `т.к. он закешировал count` - ну ок, но чтение-запись volatile переменной создает happen before (как то так оно называется) и все изменения до этой записи стают видны другому потоку (опять же, Вы это и наблюдаете)

Comment: @KoVadim
Если я не ошибаюсь (а я могу ошибаться) happens before просто запрещает перестановку инструкций при оптимизации кода. Но в случае выполнения кода различными потоками это по идее никакого значения не имеет.
Касательно volatile. Т.е. поток может закэшировать переменную, а может и не закешировать?

Comment: по volatile - все на усмотрение jvm и компилятора. по поводу "перестановок" - тут чуть сложнее.

Comment: happens before не только про перестановку, но и про видимость изменений, меняя/читая volatile флаг другому потоку становится видно и изменение count. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8_Java

Comment: представьте себе учителя физкультуры, который стоит перед шеренгой учеников и отмечает их наличие. Но на улице холодно, а кол-во отсутствующий учеников невелико. Поэтому, он делает переклчику, а если кого то нет, он просто запоминает. Если собралось 2-3 отсутствующий, он снимает перчатку и отмечает всех накопившихся. А рядом стоит глухой директор, который смотрит в журнал и по факту видит "не сразу". А есть ученики "volatile", на который отметка вносится сразу (записав и предыдущих). В теории, даже завершив перекличку, изменения в журнал могут попасть только вечером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на похожий вопрос (в чуть другом ракурсе) есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254488/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7/1255164#1255164). В этом ответе акцентирую то, что важно для этого вопроса.

> Ожидаемое поведение - первый поток зациклится, поскольку он закеширует boolean

Поток может зациклиться и это не будет противоречить спецификации. Но так же допустима реализация (может не такая оптимальная), в которой не будет зацикливания. Спецификация требует определенного поведения, когда `volatile` присутствует, но ничего не требует, когда его нет. Делать ли изменения в одном потоке видимыми в другом - это дело реализации (компилятора и JVM). То что вы наблюдаете, вполне возможно, стечение обстоятельств, а не фича реализации.

Еще один момент, что тут у вас используется системный вызов (`System.out.println`), а внутри него могут быть дополнительные синхронизации (например, `synchronized` метод или блок) и именно из-за этого даже без volatile случается барьер памяти и переменные стают видны в других потоках. Я такое [наблюдал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1286989/218971).

> Я добавляю volatile только флагу, но не count переменной

1. поток1 пишет в `count`
2. поток1 пишет в `flag`
3. поток2 читает из `flag`
4. поток2 читает из `count`

Тут все пары операций (1-2, 2-3 и 3-4) связаны отношением happens-before, т.е. `1 happens-before 2` и т.д. Из-за транзитивности happens-before также имеем, что `1 happens-before 4`.

Если две операции связаны отношением happens-before (`a happes-before b`) то результат `a` виден `b`. В данном случае это означает, что запись в `count` видна при чтении `count` из другого потока, даже если `count` не volatile.  Это все благодаря тому, что `запись в volatile переменную happens-before чтения из этой же volatile переменной`.

Ответы на дополнительный вопросы из комментария:

> Потоки могут синхронизировать общую переменную друг с другом без внешних механизмов. ... за счет чего происходит синхронизация

Много чего может быть. Это такая деталь реализации, которая не имеет отношения к семантике самого языка java. На практике это не делается специально, а "так выходит" само собой. Ну например, самый простой механизм - это когда компилятор + JVM вместо того чтоб работать с переменной в регистре процессора (и тогда она выходит по сути закеширована, так как у каждого потока будет своя копия регистров), сохраняет ее прямо в память. Такое сохранение прямо в оперативную память и будет по сути тем что называют "синхронизация локального кеша" (так как этого самого кеша нет).

Какой именно код сгенерирует компилятор зависит от многих причин. Более того по ходу выполнения программы JIT-компилятор может изменять скомпилированный код, если решит, что выгоднее его перекомпилировать, чтоб он быстрей выполнялся. Например, он может заметить, что в программе чтение и запись переменной происходит очень редко, и тогда чтоб не занимать регистр (и использовать его для хранения других данных, которые используются часто) компилятор может писать/читать эту переменную напрямую из памяти. Да это будет медленней, но так как это происходит редко, а освободившийся регистр позволит более значительно ускорить работу с другой переменной - то это выгодно. Таким образом получится, что он нечаянно будет всегда делать синхронизацию этой переменной, хотя это просто побочный эффект другой оптимизации.

> Гарантирует строгое обращение в память (и чтение и запись) именно volatile

Не совсем. Не нужно вообще мыслить в таких категориях как "строгое обращение в память". Единственное, что volatile гарантирует, это что изменения записанные в переменную (и в другие до нее) будут видны при последующих чтениях. Будет ли при этом запись в память или нет - это уже личное дело компилятора. Прямая запись в (и чтение из) память - это один из способов этого добиться. Но среда может решить это делать и иначе (или не делать вовсе). Например, если компилятор понимает, что других потоков, которые могут читать эту переменную, в принципе нет, то и смысла писать в память нет, так как все равно это будет зря. Правило happens-before не нарушится, если единственную volatile переменную доступную только из какого-то одного потока трактовать как не volatile.

> Вхождение в секцию с блокировкой заставляет поток синхронизировать кеш с оперативной памятью.

Да. А так же выход из `synchronized` блока/метода. Точнее это устанавливает happens-before соотношения между операциями до/после захвата/освобождения монитора. Опять же, если компилятор может доказать, что этого можно не делать (т.к. нет других потоков, который читают или пишут), то он может и опустить собственно синхронизацию с памятью.

Comment: Позвольте уточнить, чтобы все утрясти в голове.
1. Потоки могут  синхронизировать общую переменную друг с другом без внешних механизмов. Но спецификации это не гарантирует. Так?
2. Если первый пункт корректен - за счет чего происходит синхронизация? Поток может просто не закешировать переменную, или он кеширует ее всегда, просто иногда может обратиться в память для "выгрузки" значения?
2. Гарантирует строгое обращение в память (и чтение и запись) именно volatile.
3. Вхождение в секцию с блокировкой заставляет  поток синхронизировать кеш с оперативной памятью.

Comment: меня только одно смущает: в вопросе `entity` является разделяемым ресурсом. Он не объявлен как потокобезопасный, так почему обращение к нему не экранируется чем нибудь? Или это считается нормальной практикой?